# Bootstrap Installation Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bower

I've been trying to install Bootstrap into a project that I'm working on, but I'm being hit with `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery`. I've installed both through Bower, so I'm not sure whether that's related, but it's not having issues finding the files, so I don't think it is. Upon Googling the issue, I realized that the order in which I reference the script files matters, so I changed it to reflect what I had read, but that didn't fix the issue. When I looked into the directories in the file explorer, I saw a file called core.js, but including that didn't help either. I fairly certain that it's something to do with the way I reference files, so I'll provide that code, but feel free to ask if anything more is required.

index.html (root folder, following text is in body):

```
<script src="./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>

<script src="./bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="./bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="./bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="./bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="./bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>

<script src="angulator.js"></script>
<script src="./components/calculator/calculator.controller.js"></script>

<script src="./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might have confused jQuery with angular. You are not including jQuery, but you are including angular (including angular-material, which is a competing framework to bootstrap).

If you want to use bootstrap with angular, you probably want to use [ng-bootstrap](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap) instead of the standard Bootstrap JS, since it allows you to interact with Bootstrap components from inside your angular components. If you do this via the "standard" (non ng-bootstrap) JavaScript, things will start falling apart as soon as the Bootstrap JS mutates the DOM. You would also be unable to infer the view state from your component state (since you would need to call the functions of the bootstrap JS instead of data binding), which is pretty much the whole idea of angular.

Comment: I read that ng-bootstrap requires Angular 4 here: https://alligator.io/angular/ng-bootstrap/ I don't understand it though. My first line is `<script src="./bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>`. Is that not a reference to jQuery? UPDATE: Sorry, didn't realize I forgot to include that line in the question

Comment: That is a reference to jQuery, but the path might be wrong. I think it should be `./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js` (note the "dist" - have a look at the file system to confirm this). And yes, ng-bootstrap requires angular 4.

Comment: The path is definitely correct, as there are no file not found errors, and as far as I know I'm using Angular 1

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right. The bower people named "angularjs" "angular" (the latter being usually used to refer to angular2+). The correct package for angular 1 would be [Angular UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) then. If you use this, you won't need the standard bootstrap js or jQuery. If you still want to use jQuery and the regular BoostrapJS: Which versions are you using? What happens if you issue a `jQuery.fn.jquery`in your browsers debugging console?

Answer (score 0):

You need jquery to remove the error

bower install jquery

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you referencing jQuery in the code you provided. You've installed it via Bower, but you will still need to add a reference to it.

```
<script src="./bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="./bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="./bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="./bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="./bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="./bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>

<script src="angulator.js"></script>
<script src="./components/calculator/calculator.controller.js"></script>
```

Comment: I reference jQuery in the first line: `<script src="./bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Import jQuery script before, like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="./bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="./bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="./bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="./bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
```

...

Comment: I reference jQuery script in the first line: <script src="./bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap needs `jQuery` to work properly

Here is how you should include them both

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Bootstrap</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"> <!--Bootstrap CSS-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"> <!--Your custom css file-->
        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

    </head>
    <body>

        
        <!-- Your content goes here -->


    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script><!--jQuery -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><!--Bootstrap js-->
    <script src="js/main.js"></script> <!--Your custom javascript file-->
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have made a mistake while referencing JQuery.

It should be like :

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and also make sure that you have included it before any  other script file.

The correct way to include JQuery is also given on bower.io under Use Packages https://bower.io/